# ASP.NET boilerplate Display error for decimal in french language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-boilerplate

I have an error when I display a decimal value. I use two languages ​​(English / French) and the problem only concerns the French language, with English language the value is displayed correctly and I can modify it.

Error message:

> The specified value "0,00" is not a valid number. The value must match
>   to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?" jquery.min.js:3

// My Model

```
public Decimal? Tax_percent { get; set; }
```

// My View

```
<input type="number" name="Tax_percent" class="form-control@(!Model.Tenant.Tax_percent.HasValue ? "" : " edited")" value="@Model.Tenant.Tax_percent" step="0.01" min="0" max="100">
```

I tried to display it with "DisplayFor" and "EditorFor" without success.

Thanks

Comment: Which database you have?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: Databse means SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: i use SQL Server

Comment: Check abplanguage table's encoding. It should be utf8

Comment: I'm sorry but where do you find this information?

Comment: right-click the database that you want and click Properties. Click the Options page, and select a collation from the Collation drop-down list.

Comment: Value is "French_CI_AS"

Comment: I dont have SQL Server on my machine. But it should be similar to **utf8 default collation**

Comment: Could you please try to run this query in sql server DB `alter table <YourDBName>.abplanguages convert to character set @utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Thanks, i will ask to the database guy. I keep you inform.